# Dynamic modification of struts jquery tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, tags, struts2-jquery

New to struts jquery tags. Wanted to know, is it possible to dynamically change the content type of the grid. I was partially successful doing that using formatter.

```
<s:url id="insertAttrTypeUrl"
                        action="populateCreateAttributeSetupGrid">
                    </s:url>

                    <sjg:grid id="insertAttrTyGrid" href="%{insertAttrTypeUrl}"
                        dataType="json" name="insertAttrTyGrid"
                        formIds="attributeSetupForm" caption="Create New Attribute Type"
                        reloadTopics="reloadInsertAttrTyGrid"
                        onSelectRowTopics="insertAttrTyRowSelect" gridModel="insertGridViewList" 
                        gridview="true" viewrecords="true" requestType="post" height="150">

                        <sjg:gridColumn name="columnName" index="columnName"
                            id="columnName" title="COLUMN NAME" align="center"
                            sortable="false" width="140" />

                        <sjg:gridColumn name="columnValue" index="columnValue"
                            id="columnValue" title="COLUMN VALUE" align="center"
                            sortable="false" formatter="formatColumnValue" width="160" />

                        <sjg:gridColumn name="displayColumnType" index="displayColumnType"
                            id="displayColumnType" title="DATA TYPE" align="center"
                            sortable="false" width="135" />

                    </sjg:grid>

function formatColumnValue(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
        var colName = rowObject.columnName;
        if (cellvalue == null) {
            cellvalue = "";
        }
        if(colName==="CREATED_BY" || colName==="TYPE_NAME" || colName==="DISPLAY_NAME"){
            var rdioHtml = "<input type='text' style='text-align:center; width:150px;' name='columnValue' id='columnValue'" 
                + options.rowId + "' value='"+cellvalue+"'/>";
                        return rdioHtml;
        }



        if(colName==="DESCRIPTION"){
            var txtA = "<input type='textarea' cols='20' rows='5' style='text-align:center; width:150px;' name='columnValue' id='columnValue'" 
                + options.rowId + "' value='"+cellvalue+"'/>";
                        return txtA;
        }
```

Text area is not coming instead ,the normal textbox is being printed. Please suggest ,if we need to use any other tags.

Comment: You're not using textarea.

Comment: Why not to use jqGrid options?

Comment: @AleksandrM  Will this not give me a textarea?

Comment: @RomanC in my projects they are using sj frid everywhere..

Comment: @RomanC ,I still want to know, how to achieve this using jqgrid. I'll definitely want to try that

Comment: @PreethiJha Since it is not coming then no.